# Laravel return view from method in controller

Tags: laravel

In a Laravel 5.7 controller, this works:

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    return view('test);
}
```

But this doesn't (the result is a blank page, no html is generated, no error message is shown)

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    $this->show_view();
}

private function show_view()
{
    return view('test);
}
```

If I add `dd('this is a test');` in the private function `show_view` right before `return view('test);`, that message is displayed so the `show_view` method is called properly, but returning the view doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$this->show_view();` to `return $this->show_view();` and it should work. You're getting a blank page because while you successfully render the view, you don't return it back to Laravel at all.